# Why can't you add attributes to object in python?

Tags: python, attributes, instances

(Written in Python shell)

```
>>> o = object()
>>> o.test = 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    o.test = 1
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'test'
>>> class test1:
    pass

>>> t = test1()
>>> t.test

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    t.test
AttributeError: test1 instance has no attribute 'test'
>>> t.test = 1
>>> t.test
1
>>> class test2(object):
    pass

>>> t = test2()
>>> t.test = 1
>>> t.test
1
>>>
```

Why doesn't object allow you to add attributes to it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Notice that an `object` instance has no `__dict__` attribute:

```
>>> dir(object())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__']
```

An example to illustrate this behavior in a derived class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = {}
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Quoting from the docs on [`slots`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> [...] The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.

EDIT: To answer ThomasH from the comments, OP's test class is an "old-style" class.  Try:

```
>>> class test: pass
...
>>> getattr(test(), '__dict__')
{}
>>> getattr(object(), '__dict__')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

and you'll notice there is a `__dict__` instance.  The object class may not have a `__slots__` defined, but the result is the same: lack of a `__dict__`, which is what prevents dynamic assignment of an attribute. I've reorganized my answer to make this clearer (move the second paragraph to the top).

Comment: So, you are saying that the *object* class is using \_\_slots\_\_ in one way or another, to prevent assignment of instance members. Is this an assumption or a fact (i.e. is it in the implementation of *object*)? Because the mere absence of \_\dict\_\_ from an *object* instance is not indicative. Instances of the OP's *test1* class show the same missing \_\_dict\_\_ when called with dir(), but allow nevertheless assignment of instance members.

Comment: @ThomasH, please see the note I added to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Good question, my guess is that it has to do with the fact that `object` is a *built-in/extension type*.

```
>>> class test(object):
...  pass
...
>>> test.test = 1
>>> object.test = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'
```

IIRC, this has to do with the presence of a `__dict__` attribute or, more correctly, `setattr()` blowing up when the object doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute.