# Dynamic attribute assignment

Tags: python, dynamic, attributes, variable-assignment

I was trying out dynamic attribute assignment for testing purposes and discovered following behavior:

```python
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> bar = Spam()
>>> bar.a = 1
>>> spam = object()
>>> spam.a = 2
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Why is the first version with a derived class legit, but the second direct usage of `object` not? It seems a bit strange to me because deriving hasn't changed anything that has obviously something to do with how variable assignment is handled.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1285269/1015178

Comment: Agreed. I didn't check for an existing question carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `object` is a native type, meaning that it's implemented in C code and does not support dynamic attribute assignment, for performance reasons. The same can be said for most Python native classes, such as `str` or `int`.

But Python allows you to subclass any native type and your subclasses do support dynamic assignment.

You can disable it for performance reasons on your classes too, using the `__slots__` special attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`object` instances don't have a `__dict__`.

```
>>> hasattr(object(), '__dict__')
False
```

And therefore can't have any attributes added to them.