# When does setattr works?

Tags: python, class

I faced a nececssity to add atribute to one of classes from cv2 library (simply id of the object). But when I try

```
setattr(keypoint, 'id', 1)
```

I get the error `'cv2.KeyPoint' object has no attribute 'id'`

Whereas object of semi defined class:

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = 1
test = testclass(2)
setattr(test, 'id', 3)
```

works and now `test.id` returns 3. Why `setattr` does not work for `cv2.KeyPoint` object? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It's possible `cv2.KeyPoint` is a C object, not a Python one, so you can't add arbitrary properties to it. You'd see the same if you tried to add them to e.g. a string.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285269/why-cant-you-add-attributes-to-object-in-python You can `setattr()` to it if it contains a `__dict__`.

Comment: Note `keypoint.id = 1` wont work either.  For reasons commented on.  But it’s not just setattr.